# Dimension of linear subspace of inear subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Task: There is a vector space $X$ in $\mathbb R^5$. $Dim(X)=3$ 
Let $V=\{A \in \mathbb R^{5,4}: imA \subset X\}$
Show that V is linear subspace in $\mathbb R^{5,4}$ and find $Dim(V)$.

My work so far: 
$A\in \mathbb R^{5,4}$ 
$imA=\{y\in \mathbb R^5: \ \exists x \in \mathbb R^4 \ \  \  y=Ax\} $
$X$ is a vector space, so it has a basis. 
$Dim(X)=3$, so let's say that basis of $X= \{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$.
To check if $V$ is a linear subspace we have to show that:
(i) $\forall x,y \in V \ \  x+y\in V$ 
(ii)$\forall x\in V \ \ \forall \alpha \in \mathbb R \ \ \alpha x \in V$

$imA\subset X$, so $\forall A\in \mathbb R^{5,4} \  \ \ Av=\alpha_1e_1+\alpha_2e_2+\alpha_3e_3$
I know that $dim(im(A))=rankA$, but I don't know if that has any use for this task.

I don't know how to continue, neither do I know how do elements of V look like, I will be thankfull for help.

Comment: The elements of $V$ are matrices (or linear maps, if you prefer).

Comment: Yes, as it is stated in the task, $V=\{A \in \mathbb R^{5,4} (...)\}$. Furthermore $V \subset \mathbb R^{5,4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to describe $V$ as the set of $5\times 4$ matrices $A$ such that $Ax\in X$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^4$.

If $A,B\in V$, then $(A+B)x=Ax+Bx$ which belongs to $X$ because both $Ax$ and $Bx$ belong to $X$; thus $A+B\in V$. If $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $A\in V$, then $(\alpha A)x=\alpha(Ax)\in X$, so $\alpha A\in V$. It's also clear that the zero matrix belongs to $V$. Therefore $V$ is a subspace.

It is not restrictive to assume that $X$ is generated by
$$
e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
e_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
(just do a change of basis, which is an isomorphism). So, what $5\times 4$ matrices $A$ satisfy the condition?